# Parsing and inserting data into SQLITE - ios

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, xml-parsing

In my iPAD application, I call a webservice to get a XML response, then I parse it and store it into my SQLITE database.

The parsing and saving are happening properly, but the problem I am having is that it is taking a very long time for it to perform the operation.

Using the mac, I saw the number of records being saved to the database. It was 395 rows where each row has 8 columns in it i.e. around 3100 records are being stored to my database.(my entity has 8 attributes in it). On the iPAD, it takes about 25 seconds to do the whole operation, which I was told is too long.
I am unable to figure out why it is taking so long and where I am going wrong.

This is the code which I use for parsing the XML and storing -

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"return"])
    {
        // Blank lab panel object
        objLabPanel = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LabPanels" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        mainElement = elementName;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{
    elementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [elementValue appendString:string];

    // Handle html codes
    elementValue = [CommonHelper encodeHTMLCharactorsForDataBaseStorage:elementValue];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"return"])
    {
        [objPatient addLabPanelsObject:objLabPanel];

        // Save
        NSError *error = nil;
        BOOL saveObj = FALSE;
        saveObj = [managedObjectContext save:&error];

        if (saveObj == FALSE)
        {
            NSLog (@"Error: %@", error);
        }
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"batteryID"] && [mainElement isEqualToString:@"return"])
    {
        objLabPanel.labPanelBatteryId = elementValue;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"batteryVersionNum"] && [mainElement isEqualToString:@"return"])
    {
        objLabPanel.labBatteryVersionId = elementValue;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"conceptCode"] && [mainElement isEqualToString:@"return"])
    {
        objLabPanel.labPanelCode = elementValue;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"conceptDescription"] && [mainElement isEqualToString:@"return"])
    {
        objLabPanel.labPanelDesc = elementValue;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"effectiveEndTime"] && [mainElement isEqualToString:@"return"])
    {
        endDate = [CommonHelper getDateFromXMLString:[NSString stringWithString:elementValue] :@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmssZ"];
        objLabPanel.labPanelEndDate  = endDate;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"effectiveStartTime"] && [mainElement isEqualToString:@"return"])
    {
        startDate = [CommonHelper getDateFromXMLString:[NSString stringWithString:elementValue] :@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmssZ"];
        objLabPanel.labPanelStartDate = startDate;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"body"])
    {
        // Release all variables at the end of xml parsing
        [self releaseVariables];
    }

    elementValue = nil;
}
```

Here is a sample of the XML I am parsing -

```
<return>
<batteryID>1234</batteryID>
<batteryVersionNum>1</batteryVersionNum>
<conceptCode>abc</conceptCode>
<conceptDescription>abc</conceptDescription>
<effectiveEndTime>2010-11-23</effectiveEndTime>
<effectiveStartTime>2010-11-23</effectiveStartTime>
</return>
<return>
<batteryID>2345</batteryID>
<batteryVersionNum>1</batteryVersionNum>
<conceptCode>bac</conceptCode>
<conceptDescription>bac</conceptDescription>
<effectiveEndTime>2010-11-23</effectiveEndTime>
<effectiveStartTime>2010-11-23</effectiveStartTime>
</return>
```

It would be great if someone could help me out with this and tell me if something is wrong with the way I am parsing and saving.

Comment: Have you run this under Instruments? It has extensive tools for investigating resource usage and helping you find where your issues are.

Comment: If I am right, I think since I save the managedObjectContext for every return tag I encounter, that is where it is taking time. is there another way for me to store all the objects at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save the MOC periodically, not for every insert. The MOC is saved when you ask for it to be saved, so it's up to you to determine when that is. Typically you should only save the MOC when it is consistent in terms of your needs (it's always consistent in terms of low-level relationships). I would wait until the end of parsing in any case.

Comment: thank you for the reply... The only doubt I had was that, If I did save the MOC once the parsing has ended, would all my objLabPanel's get stored to the database or only the last one be stored, since I do this `objLabPanel = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LabPanels" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];` for every return tag I encounter?